# MySQL get ID from a table based on email then create a row in another table using ID and more values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables **users** and **features**:

```
users
+----+-----------------+
| id | email           |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | test1@gmail.com |
|  2 | test2@gmail.com |
|  3 | test3@gmail.com |
|  4 | test4@gmail.com |
|  5 | test5@gmail.com |
+----+-----------------+

features
+------------+---------+---------------------+------------+
| feature_id | user_id | feature_name        | can_access |
+------------+---------+---------------------+------------+
|          1 |       1 | automated-investing |          1 |
|          2 |       1 | crypto              |          0 |
|          3 |       2 | crypto              |          0 |
|          4 |       3 | automated-investing |          0 |
|          5 |       4 | automated-investing |          1 |
|          7 |       1 | financial-tracking  |          1 |
|          8 |       2 | financial-tracking  |          0 |
|          9 |       3 | financial-tracking  |          1 |
|         10 |       4 | financial-tracking  |          0 |
+------------+---------+---------------------+------------+
```

I am trying to get the `id` from `users` based on `email` and then create a new row in `features` using that `id` ,`feature_name` and `can_access`(`feature_name` and `can_access` are from a request).

I am able to do it but it is split into two parts and I am looking to do it with a single query.

**Current query:**

```
// Get ID from email
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email="test5@gmail.com";
// Insert values into features 
INSERT INTO features(user_id, feature_name, can_access) VALUES(5,"crypto", 1);
```

Expected output:

```
+------------+---------+---------------------+------------+
| feature_id | user_id | feature_name        | can_access |
+------------+---------+---------------------+------------+
|          1 |       1 | automated-investing |          1 |
|          2 |       1 | crypto              |          0 |
|          3 |       2 | crypto              |          0 |
|          4 |       3 | automated-investing |          0 |
|          5 |       4 | automated-investing |          1 |
|          7 |       1 | financial-tracking  |          1 |
|          8 |       2 | financial-tracking  |          0 |
|          9 |       3 | financial-tracking  |          1 |
|         10 |       4 | financial-tracking  |          0 |
|         11 |       5 | crypto              |          1 |
+------------+---------+---------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO features (user_id, feature_name, can_access) 
   SELECT id, "crypto", 1 FROM users WHERE email="test5@gmail.com";
```

So instead of specifying the values, you use the select statement.